# How to exclude exceptions from Sentry in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, sentry

I have an installation of Symfony 4.3 and I upgrade it to 4.4.19.
On my old installation Sentry was working well with excluded_exception.
I use it like this on `sentry.yaml` :

```
sentry:
    dsn: "https://key@sentry.io/id"
    options:
        excluded_exceptions:
            - App\Exception\BadArgumentException
            - App\Exception\BadFilterException
            - App\Exception\BadRequestException
```

But when I upgrade to 4.4.19 symfony logs tells me that `excluded_exceptions` does not exist.
Sentry get each exception on my project. It works well so I don't understand why it doesn't recognize this option. (I've seen that it was add to sentry on v2.1).

I've tried to do a `composer update sentry/sentry-symfony` but nothing changes.
On my **composer.json** I have this on require part :
`"sentry/sentry": "^3.1", "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^4.0",`

So I don't know what to do now to fix this problem. I must forgot something maybe.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please check [upgrade file](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-4.0.md) for Sentry Symfony 4.0.

According to this file `sentry.options.excluded_exceptions` configuration option was removed.
To exclude exceptions you must use `IgnoreErrorsIntegration` service:

```
sentry:
  options:
    integrations:
      - 'Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration'

services:
  Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration:
    arguments:
      $options:
        ignore_exceptions:
          - App\Exception\BadArgumentException
          - App\Exception\BadFilterException
          - App\Exception\BadRequestException
```

Comment: I like how 2 years later, this is now deprecated and back to the old way.. Much forethought x)