# Invalid configuration for path "sentry.options.integrations.0": Expecting service reference, got ""Sentry\\Integration\\IgnoreErrorsIntegration""

Tags: php, symfony, sentry, symfony-4.4

I'm setting `sentry` in `Symfony4.4` to ignore some types of exceptions. Following the doc, I set `config.yml` this way:

```
sentry:
    dsn: "%sentry%"
    register_error_listener: true
    options:
        attach_stacktrace: true
        integrations:
            - 'Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration'
```

and  I added to  `services.yml`

```
Sentry\Integration\IgnoreErrorsIntegration:
        arguments:
            $options:
                ignore_exceptions:
                    - RuntimeException
```

The exceptions are logged but when I added the ignore configuration I got this error

```
Invalid configuration for path "sentry.options.integrations.0": Expecting service reference, got ""Sentry\\Integration\\IgnoreErrorsIntegration"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude exceptions from Sentry in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154926/how-to-exclude-exceptions-from-sentry-in-symfony)